# Get 403 (Forbidden) for audio tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, audio, html5-audio

I am using following JavaScript code for play audio after complete ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup(
                    {
                        cache: false,
                        complete: function () {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#page_content').show();

                            //get gold price and compire timestamp
                            var published_date = $("#goldprice").data("published");
                            var currend_date = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                            var compare_date = currend_date-published_date;
                            if( compare_date <= 10){
                                document.getElementById('ding').play();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            setInterval(function () {
                $("#page_content").load('index-content.php')
            }, 5000);
        });
```

**Audio tag:**

```
<audio id="ding" src="assets/audio/ding.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

It works well on the local host. But it does not work online. I've checked the permissions as follows:

**Folders:**
[image]
**Audio file:**
[image]

***How to fix this problem?***

Comment: try adding `rel="noreferrer"` attribute into `audio` tag.

Comment: @n-dru This error is seen: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**

Comment: 403 for audio or for index-content.php?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `audio tag` is in index.php and error for index.php

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento apache2handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If get 403 error in `index-content.php` request, then it is because you do not set the correct permissions for this file.

Set `777` (only a example) for `index-content.php`, eg.:

1. Go to your project folder

   ```
   cd /etc/var/www/project
   ```
2. Set needed permission

   ```
   chmod 777 -R index-content.php
   ```

Check the setup of your server or installed modules, such as `modSecurity`.

Comment: I contacted the server support and problem solved. This problem was resolved with the help of support. The problem was related to `modSecurity` and to disable the problem was solved. Thank you.